# Is there any way to call a method by name using the dot syntax?

Tags: javascript

It is possible to do this using "dot syntax" without using "eval" (evil)? (I know I can do with `this[methodtocall]()`)

```
    var myObj = {

      method1 : function(){
         return 1;
      },
      method2 : function(){
         return 1;
      },
      callMethod : function(methodtocall){
           this.+methodtocall+()
      },
      init : function(){
          this.callMethod("method1");
      }
   }
   myObj.init();
```

Comment: I know you said you know, but just use bracket syntax.... what's the problem?

Comment: Why would you not want to use `this[methodtocall]()`? That's the correct way to do it.

Comment: Just wondering if it exist any way to do it... I want to maintain the same syntax across the system.

Comment: How do you propose that ECMAScript should know that the identifier in `this.methodtocall` should be resolved as a local variable (i.e. as `this[methodtocall]`) or property name (`this.methodtocall`)?

Comment: `this.+methodcall+(params)` || `this.{methodcall}.anotherproperty` || `this.[methodcall](params)` || ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, aside from `eval` or an equivalent, it's not possible with the dot notation member operator.

If you want to maintain consistent syntax, then always use the square bracket notation of the member operator.

```
  callMethod : function(methodtocall){
       this[methodtocall]()
  },
  init : function(){
      this["callMethod"]("method1");
  }
```

Comment: I think the system is too big for that... I will accept the limitation and work with the square bracket for individual cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
var myObj = {
  method1 : function(){ return 1; },
  method2 : function(){ return 2; },
  callMethod : function(methodtocall){
       if(typeof methodtocall=== 'function') {
           methodtocall();
       }
  },
  init : function(){ this.callMethod(this.method1); }
}
myObj.init();
```

Comment: That alters the calling context when `method1` is called. Not important in the example code, but could have unwanted impact in actual code.